# jersey : receive response from web-service as json file

Tags: java, json, web-services, jersey, jersey-client

nni have a problem calling a web service using jersey client.
I tried successfully as a test with : "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20location%3D%2248907%22&format=json"

using this code :

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20location%3D%2248907%22&format=json");
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
}
String json = response.getEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(json);
```

but i can't do it when i call amazon webservice : http://ws.amazon.com/widgets/q?Operation=GetResults&Keywords=cool&SearchIndex=All&multipageStart=0&InstanceId=0&multipageCount=10&TemplateId=8002&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=US

Is it because, I get a json file as response ?

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with the Amazon web service with various form HTTP requests. I finally figured out that the problem is because of the User-Agent value sent in the HTTP Header.

For some reason, Amazon Rest Service is not able to handle the presence of period character . in the HTTP Header under User-Agent.

When sending a HTTP request with . as below

```
GET http://ws.amazon.com/widgets/q?Operation=GetResults&Keywords=cool&SearchIndex=All&multipageStart=0&InstanceId=0&multipageCount=10&TemplateId=8002&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=US HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Java.
Host: ws.amazon.com
Connection: keep-alive
```

Amazon WS sends a HTTP response without Body content

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 27 Sep 2013 19:29:54 GMT
Server: Server
Content-Length: 0
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Cneonction: close
Content-Type: text/plain
```

If the . is removed from the Content-Type, the response body does contain the detailed Json Content. This most likely looks like an issue on Amazon Rest Service implementation.

You can change the code as follows to see the Json content and get away with the problem

```
 ClientResponse response = webResource.header("User-Agent", "SomeAgentNameWithoutPeriodChar").get(ClientResponse.class);
```

Comment: It also returns a jsonp.  I have always had to filter that before parsing.

Comment: I highly recommend Fiddler for testing these services.  If on linux, use wireshark.

Comment: anyway to do it without Fiddler ?